# org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized

Tags: xml, unix, ant, jaxb

Hi in our project we are using XJC ant task for xsd2schema generation after that we are compiling the src files and grouping them into a schema jar.
the classpath we have for that is:

```
jaxb-ri-2.2.6 - jaxb-impl.jar,jaxb-api.jar,jaxb-xjc.jar
```

This ant task is working fine in eclipse and jar got created , but it is throwing errors in unix environment.

The Error is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.

That error gone , when we added "xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar" to unix build classpath, but the jar generated was different from the jar that generated using eclipse.

eclipse build jar- it has only few classes
unix build jar- it has impl folder and so many classes

In both the cases the jaxb jars were the same.
Please help me with this issue....Please...................

Comment: I had a classpath nightmare using grails; forcing xercesImpl 2.9.1 resolved for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you have Maven, add this to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Upgrade or add your xercesImpl jar file located in `jre/lib/endorsed` folder to xercesImpl 2.9.1. You can simply download it and replace it. It must work.

Answer (score 6):

You need jdk 7. JDK 8 have this issue with maven tests.

Answer (score 4):

upgrade xercesImpl.jar to the latest version, and make sure it is loaded, it will work with JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

Please add xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar into [JDK Path]/jre/lib/endorsed directory. It would solve the issue for Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the workspace was using JRE instead of JDK

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded tomcat to version 9
Follow this:

1. Remove xerces-1.2.3.jar
2. Add xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar